# Haskell: Algebraic data type from List?

Tags: haskell

Assume I have a list [A, B, C]. Is there any way I can declare an algebraic data type based on that list with the following semantics:

```
data V = A | B | C
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what kind of permutation lists you are generating and exactly what kind of ADTs you would like to get out of them? It's generally impossible to define new ADTs at runtime, but if you want to programmatically generate a large ADT at compile time, it can be done using Template Haskell.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is abstract data types generated dynamically, which sounds fairly non-standard in any language with ADTs.

What you could do is have a data type with a single constructor, and then a so-called *smart-constructor*, which imposes some logic on what values can be passed to the constructor.

```
data PermList a = PermList ([a] -> Bool) [a]

permList :: ([a] -> Bool) -> [a] -> PermList a
permList f xs | f xs      = PermList f xs
              | otherwise = undefined
```

Comment: I don't understand why the `[a] -> Bool` is stored as data

Comment: How can you define several such constructors if you don't make the function a parameter?

Comment: Just use `data PermList a = PermList [a]`.  You can still do the check in the smart constructor, you don't have to carry it around with the object -- unless you had an intended purpose for using it again after the list's construction...